# What cookie should have Http-only tag

Tags: cookies

I am checking the http-only tag of some webpages and I a have a doubt when I'm trying to check. For example in the following image:

[image: Cookies]

There are some cookies with the http-only flag active but I don't know if these cookies contain tokens or important information. How can I know that? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You usually don't know what is in the cookie, as its information is to be only used by the server. Some servers encrypt the cookie to protect its contents and to prevent the user from changing it.

Now, for the `HttpOnly` flag.

It was something "invented" by [Microsoft on IE6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533046.aspx). It's an extra flag intented *for the browser* to not allow client-side scripts to access the cookie. If the flag is not set, `document.cookies` will return its contents and a XSS exploit can compromise the user cookies. With the flag set, browser will not allow any client-side scripts to read its contents, and will only send its contents to the webserver.

If the cookie data is useful for the client (like the language, or sorting preferences, or any client side preference), don't set `HttpOnly` flag. If the data is used only on the server side (like `PHPSESSID`, `ASPSESSION` or anything the client side does not use), set `HttpOnly` and make harder to a XSS exploit to steal the cookies.

Comment: thanks a lot. But if I want to make a study about the correct use of the flag. I can't check if the cookies setting with the flag contain relevant information or not?

Comment: @elvaqueroloconivel1: to decide if httponly should be set you need to know what the application is using the cookie for. Except for some common cookie names (like given in the answer) you would need look closer at the values of the cookies to decide if they might be of use on the client side and you might need to analyze both client and server side of the application. Just looking at the cookie like you try is not enough in most cases.